# How can I mock typeof on an object in typescript?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Weird question today, I have a bug where if `typeof(transaction)` returns `object` instead of the object name, the code will behave differently. I fixed the problem with `transactionType` parameter to my function, but I had to leave the old logic for retro-compatibility.

```js
    let userId: string;
    
    if (transactionType === TransactionTypes.A) {
      userId = (transaction as TransactionA).userid;
    } else if (transactionType === TransactionTypes.B) {
      userId = (transaction as TransactionB).user.id;
    } else if (
      transactionType === TransactionC
    ) {
      userId = (transaction as TransactionC).userId;
    } else {
      console.log("LEGACY TRANSACTION TYPE USED...");
      // Legacy code, caused an issue when typeof returns "object"
      userId =
        (transaction as TransactionA).userid ||
        (transaction as TransactionC).userId ||
        (transaction as TransactionB).user.id;
    }
```

When `typeof` returns`object`, I get a `null` return for `userId`. I want to be able to test that my new `TransactionType` logic does indeed work.

To do so, I need to have a test where `typeof` returns `object`. I tried passing the following to my function but I get a type error with my linter.

Here's the function declaration:

```js
  private getTransactionValues(
    transaction:
      | TransactionA
      | TransactionB
      | TransactionC,
    transactionType?: TransactionTypes,
    ): TransactionValues {
       //...
    }
```

My attempt at having `typeof` returning `object`:

```js
const transaction: TransactionB = (generateRandomTransaction() as Object);

getTransactionValues({
  transaction,
//~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ error linter "object not TransactionA | TransactionB | TransactionC"
  transactionType: TransactionType.A,
});
```

**Is it possible to mock a property with my object to have it return type `object` when passed to the function `typeof`?**

Comment: How about... `typeof(null) === 'object'`?

Comment: But I can't have the object equal to null for my test, typescript is converted to javascript which doesn't care about types, that's why this behavior of having a type `TransactionB` may return `object` when passed to `typeof`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright! So after playing around forever, figured out you could simply convert to `unknown` then to the target type and that will make `typeof` function return `object`, here's a code exemple:

```js
const transaction: TransactionB = generateRandomTransaction() as unknown as TransactionB;

console.log(typeof(transaction));

// output: object
```

Apparently passing via an `unkown` cast is enough to confuse typescript into creating an `object` type once converted to javascript.